# Can I write my movement script shorthand?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and C# coding, and I wanted to see if the code I have written for movement could be written more shorthand or even just improving how the movement flows. I think seeing the shortened solutions to my problem will also help me when I add more scripts onto this. Thanks!

```
//Variables
Rigidbody rb;
public GameObject player;
public float speed = 4f;
private float minLimit = 0.51f; //MinLimit is the height you need to be below so you can jump
private float airTime = 0.875f; //The amount of time spent in the air if you press a movement key
private float maxLimit = 3.66f; //Maxlimit is the maximum jump height
```

Below is the movement script. Imagine this copied and pasted for all four directions. The player travels in the opposite direction to normal because of the (I think) camera position.

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        if (transform.position.y > minLimit && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && transform.position.y < maxLimit)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(1, -airTime, 0) * speed;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && player.transform.position.y < minLimit)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(1, 2, 0) * speed;
            }
            if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * speed;
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3 (1, 0, 1) * speed;
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(1, 0, -1) * speed;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, get in the habit of using `else if` instead of just `if`. A lot of those if statements will never be true if the one above is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. Since you're new to coding at least in C# and Unity, do take in this advice first: Keep doing what you do - make it work first, *then* see whether you can improve on it. :)

To begin with, I'd suggest you to not use `KeyCode` based input, but rather investigate how the [Input Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html) works. For the time being, this is the standard way of declaring input keybindings without having to think about the actual keys in code. With the Unity versions following 2019.3, another method has emerged, but this might be a bit too complicated right now.

What the Input Manager allows you to do is to define a specific action, say `Fire`, and then bind keys, mouse movements, buttons and joystick input to it. In code, you'd refer to that action using e.g. [GetAxis](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) or [GetButtonDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html) with the *name* of the action:

```cs
Input.GetButtonDown("Fire")
```

If you decide to change the key bindings later on, you don't need to touch your code.

For your code, I'd suggest to fist lay everything out into individual variables that have "speaking" names:

```
var moveLeft = Input.GetButton("Left"); // Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A);
var moveUp = Input.GetButton("Up");     // Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow);
var moveDown = Input.GetButton("Down"); // Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow);
var jump = Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"); // Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space);

if (moveLeft)
{
    if (!jump && transform.position.y > minLimit && transform.position.y < maxLimit)
    {
        // No need to check for "Left Arrow || A" again, because you already did.
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(1, -airTime, 0) * speed;
    }
    else
    {
        if (jump && player.transform.position.y < minLimit)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(1, 2, 0) * speed;
        }
        if (!moveUp && !moveDown)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * speed;
        }
        if (moveDown)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3 (1, 0, 1) * speed;
        }
        if (moveUp)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(1, 0, -1) * speed;
        }
    }
}
```

Next, try to remove the nesting by inverting conditions, or leaving the method at the earliest time possible:

```cs
private void Update()
{
    var moveLeft = Input.GetButton("Left");
    if (moveLeft) MoveLeft();
}

private void MoveLeft()
{
    var moveUp = Input.GetButton("Up");
    var moveDown = Input.GetButton("Down");
    var jump = Input.GetButtonDown("Jump");

    if (!jump && transform.position.y > minLimit && transform.position.y < maxLimit)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(1, -airTime, 0) * speed;
        return;
    }

    // Note the use of "else if" here. You are overwriting "rb.velocity"
    // in every block, so the last condition wins. In this change,
    // the first condition to be true is applied, but it makes the priorities
    // explicit.
    if (jump && player.transform.position.y < minLimit)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(1, 2, 0) * speed;
    }
    else if (!moveUp && !moveDown)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * speed;
    }
    else if (moveDown)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3 (1, 0, 1) * speed;
    }
    else if (moveUp)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(1, 0, -1) * speed;
    }
}
```

Going further, try to avoid lookups of properties such as `transform.position` and try to avoid instance creation wherever possible. It doesn't have a big influence on your current code, but let's try this out:

```cs
// Note that directions should always be normalized as they would otherwise
// introduce different "strength" factors.
private readonly Vector3 LeftJumpDirection = new Vector3(1, 2, 0).normalized;
private readonly Vector3 LeftDirection = new Vector3(1, 0, 0).normalized;
private readonly Vector3 DownDirection = new Vector3 (1, 0, 1).normalized;
private readonly Vector3 UpDirection = new Vector3(1, 0, -1).normalized;

private void float jumpSpeed = 1f;

private void Update()
{
    var moveLeft = Input.GetButton("Left");
    if (moveLeft) MoveLeft();
}

private void MoveLeft()
{
    var moveUp = Input.GetButton("Up");
    var moveDown = Input.GetButton("Down");
    var jump = Input.GetButtonDown("Jump");

    // This property is cached here since we only read from it.
    var position = transform.position;

   // Also, let's add clear names ...
    var inAir = position.y > minLimit && position.y < maxLimit;
    var canJump = position.y < maxLimit;

    if (!jump && inAir)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(1, -airTime, 0) * jumpSpeed;
        return;
    }

    // Note the use of "else if" here. You are overwriting "rb.velocity"
    // in every block, so the last condition wins. In this change,
    // the first condition to be true is applied, but it makes the priorities
    // explicit.
    if (jump && canJump)
    {
        rb.velocity = JumpDirection * jumpSpeed;
    }
    else if (!moveUp && !moveDown)
    {
        rb.velocity = LeftDirection * speed;
    }
    else if (moveDown)
    {
        rb.velocity = DownDirection * speed;
    }
    else if (moveUp)
    {
        rb.velocity = UpDirection * speed;
    }
}
```

So far, your code only changed its readability (though, keep in mind that code is read by humans, not by machines).

For the next steps, here's some pointers:

- Your object's `transform` (property) has a `forward` property that points in the forward direction of your object.
- Always [normalize](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-normalized.html) your direction vectors, then scale them (e.g. by `speed`).
- If you need to think about different directions at the same time, add your direction vectors, then normalize again.
- To jump, maybe try to add an [impulse force](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) to your rigidbody by calling `rb.AddForce(Direction * Intensity, ForceMode.Impulse)`.

With these information, try to keep the concerns separated:

```cs
private void Update()
{
    // GetAxis already gives you a notion of positive or negative, e.g.
    // left or right. Try using axisValue * transform.forward.
    var moveIntensity = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    if (moveIntensity != 0) TryMove(moveIntensity);

    var jump = Input.GetButtonDown("Jump");
    if (jump) TryJump();

}
```

I personally like to separate these actions into `DoSomething()` and `TryDoSomething()`, where I'm only ever calling `DoSomething()` when something should be done for sure, and `TryDoSomething()` when that call could fail due to further logic. Here, `TryJump()` would indicate that the user expressed the *wish* to jump, but it might not result in any state change, e.g. because the user was mid air.

Maybe this already gives you some ideas.

#### Example code from somewhere else

Since you were asking about how to generalize your code for multiple directions and I just answered you to to have *different* code, but didn't give you a different solution - here's an extra. This is some code I've been using for a player controller some time ago that involves walking and jumping:

```cs
[SerializeField]
private float moveSpeed;

[SerializeField]
private float jumpForce;

[SerializeField]
private float groundDistance = 0.7f;

private Rigidbody _rig;

private void Awake()
{
    _rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void Update()
{
    Move();

    // In Unity, select "Edit > Project Settings > Input" for the input configuration.
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        TryJump();
    }
}

void Move()
{
    var xInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    var zInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    // Set a new speed velocity vector.
    var dir = new Vector3(xInput, 0, zInput) * moveSpeed;

    // Patch in the y velocity without affecting it by the move speed..
    dir.y = _rig.velocity.y;

    // Assign the updated velocity to our rigid body.
    _rig.velocity = dir;

    // Update the forward direction according to the movement vector.
    var facingDir = new Vector3(xInput, 0, zInput);
    if (facingDir.sqrMagnitude > 0)
    {
        transform.forward = facingDir;
    }
}

void TryJump()
{
    // This implements ray-cast jumping:
    // We're shooting a ray downwards to see whether we're on the ground. With a player height of
    // 1 unit and the reference point at the center of the object, a maximum distance
    // of 0.7 would tell us whether there was an object up to 0.2 units below the player object.
    // We treat this as an indicator that there was solid ground, so the player can jump.
    var pos = transform.position;
    var ray = new Ray(pos + Vector3.zero, Vector3.down);

    var hit = Physics.Raycast(ray, groundDistance);
    if (hit)
    {
        // We want the force to be applied instantaneously, not accelerating the player constantly.
        // Because of this, we use "impulse" force mode.
        _rig.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Have fun! :)